# Cannot get jQuery append to work with string

Tags: jquery, append

For some inexplicable reason, jQuery append is not working for simple strings.

```
var donorFormNotValidMsg = "";
var errorMsg = "error occured";

$(donorFormNotValidMsg).append("Error occured");
$(donorFormNotValidMsg).append(errorMsg);
```

Neither of cases of using append above works, the resulting `donorFormNotValidMsg` is still just "". Why?

Comment: Why use jquery for this? `donorFormNotValidMsg += 'Error occured';` or `donorFormNotValidMsg += errorMsg;`

Comment: @user3783243 Thanks, I guess that is a better solution. But I am somehow annoyed as to why the jquery append is not working for me...

Comment: @PavelHoryna because you're not working with a DOM element (donorFormNotValidMsg) - that's why this won't work.

Comment: You never give `donorFormNotValidMsg` an ID or classname for it to know which element to append too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are working with string not DOM element so, do:

```
var donorFormNotValidMsg = "";
donorFormNotValidMsg += 'Error occurred';
```

`.appned()` will work with DOM element:

```js
var donorFormNotValidMsg = "error occur ";
var errorMsg = "error2 occurred";

$('#append_messages').text(donorFormNotValidMsg);
$('#append_messages').append("<br/>"+errorMsg);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="append_messages">
</div>
```

Note:- here `<div>` is a DOM element